# Changing the main file in a C++ netbeans project

Tags: c++, netbeans, program-entry-point

When I create a new C++ project in netbeans,it prompts me to choose a name for the main file of the project

this is the file that gets executed when I press "Run" in the IDE

does anybody know how to change this file to another one AFTER I've already created the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the name or point to a different file.

In **C++**, on NetBeans or any other **IDE**, just place `main` function on a different file (the file you want to **RUN** when you press **RUN** on the **IDE**) and you should be done.

Comment: I had to build and clean the project first,but it worked,thank you :)

Comment: what if multiple files in a project have main methods (for testing purposes)?

Comment: @Celeritas AFAIK NetBeans only lets you create 1 executable file per project. Having more than 1 `main()` functions spread though files will give you a conflict at linking stage. Workaround is separating your desired executables into projects ;)

Answer (score 2):

When we first time build  and run a c project in netbeans- if there are more than one file with main() then it prompts us to select one of those files to be run. But after that it doesn't ask us to select a main file rather it uses the same file selected earlier, every time we run the program. So how to select other main file once we have selected one file during first attempt to run. I believe this is your question.

Answer: Right click project => select Properties => select make option under Build (in categories) =>Against Build result specify your file that you want to run. You can easily browse files with main() there. See picture-[image]